# Swift generics with default value

Tags: ios, swift, generics, callback

I'm trying to implement some single solution for each callbacks in application. So I want any callback use the same class, or at least family of classes.

- Every callback can be successful or not.
- If it is successful, it can
  contain some result of operation.
- If it is not, it can contain information about what it is failed.

The common callbacks usage looks like this:

```
func foo(callback: ((success: Bool, result: Result?, error: Error?) -> Void)?) { }
```

Or:

```
func foo(success: ((result: Result) -> Void)?, failure: ((error: Error) -> Void)?) { }
```

I don't like any of them. I want to have single elegant solution for each callback. I found something similar in [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) library.

```
    enum CallbackResult<T, V> {
        case success(value: T?)
        case failure(error: V?)

        var isSuccess: Bool {

            switch self {
            case .success: return true
            case .failure: return false
            }
        }
    }

    func foo(callback: ((result: CallbackResult<Any, AnyObject>) -> Void)?) {
         callback?(result: .success(value: nil))
    }
```

This solution it nice. But like in my example, not always we need to pass any value or error as a parameter. Anyway, compiler always need to know what type generic parameters should be of. So even if I don't meter what type value is, I always should put there at least `Any` or `AnyObject` . It is overcomplicated.

I've tried to change it with class solution:

```
    class CallbackResult<T, V> {

        let isSuccess: Bool

        let value: T?

        let error: V?

        fileprivate init(success: Bool, value: T? = nil, error: V? = nil) {

            self.isSuccess  = success
            self.value      = value
            self.error      = error
        }

        static func success(value: T? = nil) -> CallbackResult {
            return CallbackResult(success: true, value: value)
        }

        static func failure(error: V? = nil) -> CallbackResult {
            return CallbackResult(success: false, error: error)
        }
    }

    func foo(callback: ((result: CallbackResult<Any, AnyObject>) -> Void)?) {
         callback?(result: CallbackResult.success(value: nil))
    }
```

It has the same functionality. But even in this way it didn't solve my problem. You can't just write like this:

```
CallbackResult<_, Error>
```

It will not work.

Maybe somebody know solution to my problem? Some way to put default value maybe^ not to write `Any` each time? Or for now there is only ugly way of using that approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Swift 3 added generic type aliases](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0048-generic-typealias.md). These might help you avoid typing all types each time.

Example:

```
typealias AnyResult<E> = CallbackResult<Any, E>
typealias AnyCallback<E> = (AnyResult<E>) -> ()

func foo(callback: AnyCallback<String>?) {
    callback?(.failure(error: "Ouch!"))
}

foo() { result in
    if result.isSuccess {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It works partially. When I'm using this: typealias AnyCallback<E> = (AnyResult<E>) -> (), I'm getting an error 'Segmentation' fault: 11